# Internet Explorer 64bit Automation using VBA

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, vba

I have this project that I need to automate opening of IE(64bit) in MS Access 2010(64bit) vba.

I have no problem automating ie in a 32bit environment but not on 64bit. Has anyone ever have this requirement? I would love to know how did you do it.

setup:
- windows 7 64 bit
- MS Access 2010 64 bit
- ie 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're running the 64bit browser?

The default browser on 64bit Windows 7 is the 32 bit browser (because most 3rd party plugins are 32bit).

There should be a link somewhere for Internet explorer 64bit (if you type *Internet explorer 64bit* into the start prompt you'll find it).

Comment: Yup I'm sure. Because the value of IE.Path = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" and not "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" [ Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ] So what's interesting is even though the default browser used by the system for internet browsing is the 32 bit version of IE, in automation it use the 64 bit version. I suspect this is because the 64 bit version is the one in the "Program Files" folder, while the 32 bit version is in the new "Program Files (x86)" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FollowHyperlink method: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237946(v=office.12).aspx

Or otherwise you can use ShellExecuteEx

Comment: I'll try the ShellExecuteEx. Thank you.